# Forward url arguments to view in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to forward `projects/1` to the view, for purpose of getting the project based on the id.
I have tried to change the regex, and the name.

**Edit:** But the issue is: 
The id doesn't get forwarded (Or atleast not correctly) to the views, which results in the filter failing to find the Project based on the id.

***Urls related to the 'Project':***

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>([0-9]+))$', views.project, name='project'),
]
```

***The view for the 'Project':***

```
def project(request, project_id=1):
    template = loader.get_template("project.html")
    context = {
        'project': Project.objects.filter(project_id=project_id)
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I have added the issue, see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex seem a little incorrect to me, especially parentheses. Try this:

```
url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.project, name='project'),
```

**UPDATE**:

So you want to show only one project instead of several. In that case, change `Project.objects.filter` to `Project.objects.get` in your view.

Also, try [this awesome django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) to learn the basics

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Azoraqua does your requests actually reach the view?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: what happens when you try to access that url from the browser?

Comment: The template gets loaded, but without the actual data.

Comment: can you print `context` inside your view and post the result?

Comment: And how, if I may ask? I am quite a beginner with Python and Django.

Comment: after `context =...` just do `print(context)`. Then go that url again, and post the result from the place where you did `runserver`

Comment: The result is: `{'project': <QuerySet [<Project: Project object>]>}`
Is my way of selecting the data incorrect, using this filter?

Comment: It means that one project object was found from the database. And the problem is in your template. Please, post your template as well.

Comment: Okay, so you want to show only one project instead of several. In that case,  change `Project.objects.filter` to `Project.objects.get` in your view.

Comment: It works! Thank you for that solution, it made my day.